# Testing in Python - how can I use assertRaises in testing using 'unittest'?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, exception

I am trying to do a simple test in Python using '[unittest](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html)', to see if a class throws an exception if it gets an unsuitable input for the constructor. The class looks like this:

```
class SummaryFormula:
    def __init__( self, summaryFormula):
        self.atoms = {}
        for atom in re.finditer( "([A-Z][a-z]{0,2})(\d*)", summaryFormula):
            symbol = atom.group(1)
            count = atom.group(2)

            if pocet != "":
                self.atoms[ symbol] = int(count)
            else:
                self.atoms[ symbol] = 1
```

My test is the following:

```
    class ConstructorTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
      def testEmptyString(self):
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, ukol1.SummaryFormula(), "testtest")

    if __name__ == '__main__':
      unittest.main()
```

All I want is the test to fail, meaning that the exception of unsuitable input for constructor is not handled.

Instead, I get an error: `__init__() takes exactly two arguments (1 given)`.

What am I missing? What is the second argument I should specify?

Also, what type of Error should I use to handle exception that an input not matchable by my regexp was passed to the constructor?

Comment: I can't run the code directly as there is syntax error near for loop. Can you correct that.

Comment: I thought the indentation around for loop was not correct

Comment: @pyfunc: Sorry about that. Corrected it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That’s because your class requires a parameter while instantiating the object.

While you are passing

```
ukol1.SummaryFormula()
```

You should have been passing the parameter summaryFormula to it.

```
ukol1.SummaryFormula(someSummaryFormula)
```

Also the confusion is because your class name is SummaryFormula and the parameter that you pass to `__init__` is also SummaryFormula

Or it should this be

```
self.assertRaises(TypeError, ukol1.SummaryFormula, "testtest")
```

Comment: This was of course the first thing that I tried, but if I use self.assertRaises(TypeError, ukol1.SummaryFormula("testtest"), "testtest"), I get other error: SummaryFormula instance gas no __call__ method.    And isn't it that you specify the arguments passed to the function tested in assertRaises as a third (or fourth, fifth, ...) argument of the assertRaises() function?

Comment: @Tomas Novotny : I did add the second change while I was trying to run your code.  Repeating it here : self.assertRaises(TypeError, ukol1.SummaryFormula, "testtest")

Answer (score 28):

A more Pythonic way is to use `with` command (added in Python 2.7):

```
with self.assertRaises(SomeException):
    do_something()
```

Documentation: *[assertRaises](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)*

Comment: This is actually pretty great. Nice and clean.

Answer (score 26):

`assertRaises` is a little confusing, because you need to give it the callable, not an expression that makes the call.

Change your code to:

```
self.assertRaises(TypeError, ukol1.SummaryFormula, "testtest")
```

In your code, you are invoking the constructor yourself, and it raises an exception about not having enough arguments.  Instead, you need to give `assertRaises` the callable (ukol1.SummaryFormula), and the arguments to call it with ("testtest").  Then it can call it, catching and checking for exceptions.

Answer (score 8):

Since none of the other answers point on how you can use the context that encapsulates the code that causes the exception, here's how you can do that.

```
with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as ctx:
    <some code that throws an exception>

expected_msg = 'foo_bar_baz'
self.assertEquals(ctx.exception.message, expected_msg)
```

Attributes of interest in this `unittest.case._AssertRaisesContext`, are:

- exception
- expected
- expected_regexp
- failureException

Comment: ctx.exception does not have attribute 'message' for me, but self.assertEquals(str(ctx.exception), expected_msg) works.

Answer (score 4):

A more-generic alternate format is

```
args=['testtest']
kwargs = {}
self.assertRaises(TypeError, ukol1.SummaryFormula, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is useful if your constructor is polymorphic and you want to loop over a list of different ways of miswriting the arguments, e.g.:

```
arg_lists = [
    ['testtest'],
    ['anothertest'],
    ['YAT'],
]
for args in arg_lists:
    self.assertRaises(TypeError, ukol1.SummaryFormula, *args)
```